# String updating by group - performance improvement

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(firstname = c("John L", "Robert C", "John", "J L", "Tom F", "T F", "Tom", "Jan Paul W R", "Jan Paul", "J P W R", "J P"), 
lastname = c("Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Frost", "Frost", "Frost", "Wilson", "Wilson", "Wilson", "Wilson"), 
initial = c("JL", "RC", "J", "JL", "TF", "TF", "T", "JPWR", "JP", "JPWR", "JP")), .Names =c("firstname","lastname", "initial"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class ="data.frame")
```

I want to replace all shorter first names to longest first name in a group that has a same last name with different initials and/or firstname. So, my resulting data frame `df` would look like this:

```
     firstname lastname  initial     LongName
1       John L      Doe      JL        John L
2     Robert C      Doe      RC      Robert C
3         John      Doe       J        John L
4          J L      Doe      JL        John L
5        Tom F    Frost      TF         Tom F
6          T F    Frost      TF         Tom F
7          Tom    Frost       T         Tom F
8 Jan Paul W R   Wilson    JPWR  Jan Paul W R
9     Jan Paul   Wilson      JP  Jan Paul W R
10     J P W R   Wilson    JPWR  Jan Paul W R
11         J P   Wilson      JP  Jan Paul W R
```

At present, I am doing this using `grepl` and `if else`, as below:

```
df$LongName <- apply(df,1,function(x) {
  if(gsub("[[:space:]]","",x[["firstname"]]) == x[["initial"]]){
    Longname <- df$firstname[grepl(x[["initial"]], df$initial) & df$lastname == x[["lastname"]]]
  }
  else{
    Longname <- df$firstname[grepl(x[["initial"]], df$initial) & grepl(x[["firstname"]], df$firstname) & df$lastname == x[["lastname"]]] 
  }

  Longname[which.max(nchar(Longname))]
})
```

The code above works well but it is slow for a large `data frame` since it uses `if else`. I was thinking if I can optimize the running time. So, I am looking for an alternative approach to speed up.

Comment: can you group by initials and select the first name with max(nchar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an entertaining way using `adist` with an insertion cost of 0 to create a string distance matrix:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(firstname = c("John L", "Robert C", "John", "J L", "Tom F", "T F", "Tom", "Jan Paul W R", "Jan Paul", "J P W R", "J P"), 
                     lastname = c("Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Frost", "Frost", "Frost", "Wilson", "Wilson", "Wilson", "Wilson"), 
                     initial = c("JL", "RC", "J", "JL", "TF", "TF", "T", "JPWR", "JP", "JPWR", "JP")), .Names =c("firstname","lastname", "initial"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -11L), class ="data.frame")

df %>% 
    group_by(lastname) %>% 
    mutate(fullname = {
        # Boolean matrix of where string distance with an insertion cost of 0 is 0
        d <- adist(initial, firstname, costs = c(i = 0)) == 0; 
        # set TRUE values to the number of characters of that string
        d[d] <- nchar(firstname[col(d)][d]); 
        # return whichever firstname has the most characters
        firstname[max.col(d)]
    })
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#> # Groups:   lastname [3]
#>       firstname lastname initial     fullname
#>           <chr>    <chr>   <chr>        <chr>
#>  1       John L      Doe      JL       John L
#>  2     Robert C      Doe      RC     Robert C
#>  3         John      Doe       J       John L
#>  4          J L      Doe      JL       John L
#>  5        Tom F    Frost      TF        Tom F
#>  6          T F    Frost      TF        Tom F
#>  7          Tom    Frost       T        Tom F
#>  8 Jan Paul W R   Wilson    JPWR Jan Paul W R
#>  9     Jan Paul   Wilson      JP Jan Paul W R
#> 10      J P W R   Wilson    JPWR Jan Paul W R
#> 11          J P   Wilson      JP Jan Paul W R
```